# How can I split one data point in a stacked column chart into multiple objects?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the chartobject mouvemove event to display supplemental data depending one which data point index is being pointed at with the mouse.

My problem is that if in one series I have two events, they are represented by a single shape object on the chart so I can't display data respective for each data point. (Here the color means they are from the same organisation)

I suppose I could make a separate data series for every single datapoint but that is not elegant and I suspect excel will get mad at me if I try to add 50 or so dataseries

[image: Please see attached screenshot]

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "if in one series I have two events" (perhaps including the data table would help), but as a side note, consider swapping the X and Y axes; the dates won't be slanted and the horizontal bars are just as easy to read as vertical ones.

Comment: The 27 feb line, the blue line goes to 2, it represents two events. The chart represents that with a single shape object, but I would like it to be two distinct shape objects. So each can be separately clicked and I will display associated information elsewhere on the screen. I could make a second data series, color it the same blue color but suppose a day where I have 10 events in the same category of "blue". I would need to make 10 data series so that each even could have its own clickable shape. I am looking for a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: I'm not a chart expert, but I don't think a bar chart correctly represents the data you're looking at. The source data needs to somehow retain the notion that there are two data points in a given date - but here you're making mapping a date to *one* data point that represents the value "2"... I would think you *do* need Excel to render as many objects as you need interactive data points, one way or another. Or, the code that gets the "additional information" needs to lookup the interesting date and fetch this data to show info about the two events on that date.

Comment: Show us the code that you are using "*to display supplemental data depending one which data point index is being pointed at with the mouse*" and tell us more about this "supplemental data" and where to find it, and then we can likely help you find a workable solution. As it stands there's *discussion* material, but I don't think your question is possible to reasonably *answer*.

Comment: Yes Mathieu, the bar chart just has a value of 2 and right now it can't distinguish between the first and second element on that same day, it's just one bar with the same dpindex and series. I'm using GetChartElement to know which specific element is clicked or mousemove on. (I don't have access to the code today, but will tomorrow). I just need to know whether the user wants the first or the second element of that day. I think I will have to create different series and color them the same color. That is what I'm asking, is there a better way than this hack ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the chart element is seeing a data point that says "2" - and your code needs that to be two distinct elements to "display supplemental data", so what I would do is grab the user-selected chart element and, instead of treating that UI element like data, I would go and get the underlying data for that series wherever it's at, and use *that* to show the additional data, perhaps with some navigation buttons to move between the elements making up that "2" and update the info accordingly. It pretty much all depends on what you specifically mean by "display supplemental data".

Comment: The problem is that a bar chart that aggregates the number of events per day/organization can't work for what you're trying to do unless you embrace the aggregate nature of the data you're interacting with. That is, by "display supplemental data" you mean you're going to show additional information about *the selected date/organization*, because that's what each point stands for; this can very reasonably well include event-level sub-details, but if the chart is an aggregate, then the chart is an aggregate.

Comment: Yes, the data source says "2" for that day. I'm using the chart as a user interface. I want the user to tell me if they want to know about the first one of that day, or the second one by splitting that one datapoint of 2 into two elements of the same colour. Maybe I can use the X/Y coordinate of the cursor to determine which fraction of that shape object the user has clicked on, and then also draw little black lines on top of the shape so the user can tell where each "virtual" data point begins and end.

Comment: Or maybe I will just create one dataseries per event per day and colour them the same if they are from the same organisation.